# PowerA Wired Xbox360 Controller Not Working on Windows 10 - Device Descriptor Request Failed

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, game-controller

(I'm not sure if this is the proper StackExchange site for this, I don't use StackExchange very often, and I couldn't find any others that would fit better, apart from *potentially* Arqade)

So I have this PowerA Xbox 360 controller that I received as a gift years ago. I used it a bunch on PC, and it worked fine for a while. Then, at one point, it stopped working, so I just kinda shelved it and forgot about it. Now, I found it again and decided to try and get it working again.

Basically, the issue is that when I plug it in to my PC, Windows says "The last USB device you connected to this computer malfunctioned, and Windows does not recognize it." And when I go check in the Device Manager, I find a device called "Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed)". I tried right-clicking it and manually "updating" drivers, but I don't find any Xbox 360 controller drivers in the list.

It might be a hardware issue, because I tried using it with an adapter that lets me connect Xbox 360 controllers to my Nintendo Switch, and it didn't work either.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?